# What kind of Psychometric test is this

Tags: measurement

I’ve taken this exam as a requirement for a job.  Unfortunately, I forgot what the exam was called. All I can remember is that the exam has 100 items grouped into five or four. Each group of five or four questions contains numerical, logical, and vocabulary questions. The questions look something like this:

Something that you use when raining
**U**,  S,  G,  C,  M   (Umbrella)

A small explosive thrown by hand
**G**,  C,  W,  J,  Z    (Grenade)

An apple costs $2.50.
If you have 10,how many can you buy?

**4**,  5,  6,  4.5,  5.5

Complete the series: 1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, ?
**22**,  21,  20,  23,  24

Comment: Do you want to know what the name of the test is or how would categorised in relation to other similar tests?

Answer (score 1):

It an [Intelligence](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient) test which was not well designed based off Spearmen's work. Performance evaluations like this can lead to promotion if you score well. If you find a correlation exists in the organization I suggest you take multiple intelligence tests multiple times to learn the testing methods of questions to score better.

Comment: +1 - Hence it is not a psychometric test then is it?

Comment: @AliceD "psychometric" tells of a kind of quality of development and testing procedure its expensive like 300 to 500$ i doubt the company can afford that in mass action.

Comment: its hr Fizz Buzz an excuse to fire you or promote you or enforce a glass ceiling